# How can we add our custom function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to add my custom function in jquery library so that i can access them using $ sign.

I am trying using this way but its not working

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() { 
                alert('test'); 
             }
```

and i also want to know that can we rename any function which already available in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to define a function at `jQuery`, or jQuery alias `$` use `$` without `.fn`, which attaches function to an object or selector chained to `jQuery()` call.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("test");
}

jQuery.myFunction = myFunction;

jQuery.myFunction(); // called on `jQuery` object

jQuery.fn.myFunction = myFunction;

jQuery({}).myFunction(); // `$.fn` chained to `jQuery()` call
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```